# Symfony 5 - routing - optional parameter incorrectly assigned

Tags: routes, optional-parameters, symfony5

I work with Symfony 5. I have a route containing 2 parameters, the second of which is optional. When I call this route without passing the optional parameter, it contains something other than the null value that I assign to it by default.

There is my route :

```
/**
     * Creating and updating advert
     *
     * @Route("/advert/description/create/{owner}/{advert}", name="advert.description.create")
     * 
     * @param Owner $owner
     * @param Advert $advert
     * @param Request $request
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $manager
     * 
     * @return Response
     */
    public function descriptionForm(Owner $owner, Advert $advert = null, Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $manager): Response
    {
 
        dump($advert);
```

By example, when I use the url "https://127.0.0.1:8000/en/advert/description/create/1", the dump gives me an object with the id 2.

Answer (score 3):

Problem resolved adding theses annotations :

- @ParamConverter("owner", options={"id" = "owner"})
- @ParamConverter("advert", options={"id" = "advert"})